# Cannot display empty textview in List Fragmant when the list has no items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am displaying a list in a `listfragmant` inside a `ViewPager`. I have looked for varoius solutions but none worked for me.

**Solution 1-**

```
if ((ArrayList) myList.size() > 0) {
   setListadapter(myAdapter);
} else {
   ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
   TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
   lv.setEmptyView(emptyText);
}
```

**Solution 2-**

```
if ((ArrayList) myList.size() > 0) {
  setListadapter(myAdapter);
} else {
  setEmptyText("No Items");
}
```

When the list is empty it shows nothing and whole page is empty.I have defined the requisite XML too.

Answer (score 0):

you have three ways:
1) create fragment and add ListView to it's layout then behind Listview put Textview so when List was empty,TextView will appear.if list has child then TextView not appear.
2) if your array has no item , add one Item to your array with any text( like :"No Items") and set adapter for listview.
3) set header for your ListView(layout can be textview that you want)

Comment: According to your 2nd point "No Items" will be the list item of listview.I dont want to use it.I want to use separate empty textview with id = "android:id/empty"

Comment: you can set header for your Listview,get ListView from ListFragment and set header for it (your header's layout).layout can be anything you want(such as your textView)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to set the adapter. If the adapter is empty, then the `ListFragment` will automatically hide `ListView` and show the empty view. So, the proper way to do it would be just:

```
setEmptyText("No Items");
setListadapter(myAdapter);
```